# after click menu, PrimeFaces layout needs manual refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In My project, I want to implement that when someone access ,need to popup a login Dialogue box first (Hide the main page menu and other element.. just let u see the login box ) .then if you put in right info, hide the loginbox and display layout to u .
Now question is  : when hide the box , yeah, you can see the layout and looks nice , but when you click the link in the menu, the center all layout  display to none. But when you refresh browser again , you can see it again

I'm sure whether i update wrong id or something else .
Following is the code refer  and catch exception .Wait your answer. Very important to me . 
Best Regards and Thank .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>SingTel - eshop Operation Maintaince</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon"
                href="#{request.contextPath}/images/system/favicon.ico" />

        </f:facet>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/css/default.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/css/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.css" />

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
                if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
                    jQuery('#dialog').effect("shake", { times:5 }, 100);
                } else {
                    dlg.hide();
                    jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();
                }
            }           
        </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>    
        <p:outputPanel id="mainPanel" autoUpdate="true">
            <p:layout fullPage="true" id="layout" rendered="#{esUserSessionBean.showLogin == true ? false : true}">
                <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" closable="false"
                    collapsible="true" style="border:0px" header="MENU">
                    <h:form id="menuForm">
                        <p:slideMenu
                            style="width:272px;height:600px;margin-left:-3px;margin-top:-6px;"
                            id="tree">
                            <p:submenu label="Test EJB " icon="ui-icon-play">
                                <p:menuitem value="Test EJB " action="#{navigationBean.doNav}"
                                    update=":centerContentPanel" icon="ui-icon-arrow-4-diag">
                                    <f:param name="urlParam" value="ui/testEJB/testEJB" />
                                </p:menuitem>
                            </p:submenu>
                        </p:slideMenu>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center" style="border:0px;">
                    <p:outputPanel id="centerContentPanel">
                        <ui:include src="../#{navigationBean.pageName}.xhtml" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel id="loginPanel" autoUpdate="true">
            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" closable="false"
                visible="#{esUserSessionBean.showLogin}"
                modal="true"
                >
                <h:form id="loginForm">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
                        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{esUserSessionBean.userId}"
                            required="true" label="username" />
                        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{esUserSessionBean.password}"
                            required="true" label="password" feedback="false" />

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" 
                                actionListener="#{esUserSessionBean.login}"
                                oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) " />

                        </f:facet>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:outputPanel>



    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your #loginLink inside an `<h:panelGroup rendered=#{not bean.isLogged}"></h:panelGroup>`. The bean.isLogged will be a setter of your choice that return true if the user is connected.

With that, when you refresh the page, the link won't be displayed. Altought, I don't find your #loginLink inside your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry , That's my mistake  ,I should delete the #loginLink  ,it's not be used any more , But actually , I don't think it will be the solution

Comment: You can put the rendered="..." on the element <p:outputPanel id="loginPanel" autoUpdate="true"> it will do it. You can hide it dynamically with your jQuery script.

Comment: Actually , I can hide login box now ,My question is when i click the menu  link , will hidden all panels . I have to refresh page again in order to dispaly page correct . I think you didn't understood what i said .

Comment: If I understand, you want to reload the page to show new stuffs that are allowed only to logged users? In this case you need to use the action="" from your button <p:commandButton id="loginButton" action="page.xhtml" />. You can also use location.reload(); in oncomplete.

Comment: You can continue using actionListener and update your button as follow : <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" actionListener="{esUserSessionBean.login}" oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args);location.reload();" />

Comment: No , I have tested the code you chnaged but when i click the link in the left menu , then all layout disappear also , I still have to press F5 to refresh .
  I don't think need to change code about login panel . I think the issues is refer to the layoutUnit which id named "left" . I need to display  layoutUnit id="center" on the right ,when left layoutUnit keep on left .Do  You know ?